# Records in linked tables datasheet view does not slide with the slider?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, linked-server

I have linked tables in Access connected to SQL server. One thing that I have noticed is that if I open up a table in datasheet view and try to use the scroll bar, the records do not seem to slide with it. Let's say there are 2000 records, if I click and hold the scroll bar at the first record it will popup `Record : 1` which will disappear if I release my mouse. If I now drag the scroll bar I can see the popup flashing and changing to values like `Record : 50`, `Record : 65` etc. However, the datasheet does not change at all until I release the scroll bar.

This however is not the case with linked tables with accdb file. If I split my Access database and link the tables and scroll the tables in Datasheet view, the datasheet scrolls along the scroll bar.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is because Access linked tables use dynaset recordset by default to connect to SQL server.

From [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb188204(v=sql.90).aspx) link:

> The remaining rows are not fetched
>   immediately unless the user performs an action such as scrolling that
>   brings additional rows into view. In the background during idle time,
>   the remaining rows are gradually filled in until the recordset is
>   complete. In addition, any rows that remain visible are continually
>   refreshed according to a configurable refresh interval that defaults
>   to 60 seconds